# Direct access to stylesheet with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to enable direct access to this file: `http://example.com/assets/style.css` (located in `/assets/stylesheets/style.css`)

It works in development, but I get a 404 error in production.

config/initializers/assets.rb:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( static_pages.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( dashboard.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( style.css )
```

config/initializers/production.rb:

```
config.cache_classes = true
config.eager_load = true
config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true
config.force_ssl = false
config.log_level = :debug
config.i18n.fallbacks = true
config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Rails Asset Pipeline precompille assets and add [fingerprint](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark). You should use [Asset Pipeline Helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production) instead of hardcoding `http://example.com/assets/jquery-ui-slider-pips.css`.

If you want to use JS or CSS files without Asset Pipeline just put them to `public` directory (or any sub-directory of `public` directory) and use direct link. i.e. for `public/style1.css` file you can use URL `http://example.com/style1.css`

Comment: If you want to use JS or CSS files without Asset Pipeline just put them to `public` directory (or any sub-directory) and use direct link. i.e. for `public/style1.css` you can use URL `http://example.com/style1.css`

Comment: Ok that's obvious. I should have thought about this. Can you add this to your answer please? I'll accept it.